# Unequal input vector lengths for Neural Network

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning

I'm trying to predict whether a player of a video game will stop playing the game (0/1 for not-stopping/stopping) within the next month based on the game data from matches they've had so far.

Each match a player plays generates (X) data points, however, each player may have played a different number of matches to date (M), thus when a player's data is put into one long vector, the length of their vector will be X*M.

I'm very new to how neural networks work, but it is my understanding that each row of the dataset must have the same number of columns. Is this true?

In light of my problem, I've brainstormed three possible solutions that each make a compromise of sorts...

**[Possible solution 1: aggregate data]**

I have considered aggregating the match data as one solution, so for example instead of "points in match 1, points in match 2,..., points in match n", just having "average points per match". However I'm concerned this isn't the best compromise as averaging certain data would compromise resolution (i.e. getting a lot of points as one character in the game vs. getting a lot of points as another character may be a useful difference).

**[Possible solution 2: add zeros for missing data]**

Maybe if I have player A who plays 6 matches and player B who plays only 5 matches so far, I could just add zeros to make player B's vector as long as player A's. However I worry that adding zeros like this will be like adding a ton of noise to my data.

**[Possible solution 3: trim data to same size]**

I could set a specific number of matches for each player vector to contain, maybe 10 matches for example. So if a player has less than 10 matches they'll be dropped from the dataset or if the player has more than 10 matches, only their first 10 will appear in the dataset. The only downside here is that the only players that would have a true-prediction label of 1 (stopped playing) are players that played EXACTLY 10 games... but I'm not just interested in predicting that, I obviously want a more general prediction.

**How can I train a neural network on vectors of unequal length???**

Comment: Why down vote? Description too long?? :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So my question was probably too long for people to want to read, but anyway, my question discussed some possible ways to deal with uneven input vector lengths for a neural network (or potentially any machine learning algorithm that would require equal lengths).

One solution I hadn't thought of, but was suggested to me in a [Quora answer](https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-train-a-neural-network-when-my-input-vectors-are-not-all-the-same-length/answer/Gene-Ferruzza-1), is to **only include players that played at least 3 (some small number) games so you can include that as raw data and then for 4-n games aggregate the results**.

This is essentially a good compromise between my "Possible solution 1" and "Possible solution 3" in the question details above.